# Running declarative workflows under system account

Tags: workflow, security, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that starts a workflow (on item created). The business requirement is that after submission form must be read-only (no changes to the initial request can be made). However workflow must change certain properties of the form (e.g. approval time, approval phase etc.).

By default SharePoint workflows run under initiator account, however I am wondering would you recommend creating an event handler that is going to kick start a workflow under system account. Workflow would than be able to revoke all the contribute privileges but still be able to update the form during workflow.

**EDIT:** This is a declarative workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the OOB declarative workflow activities run in the context of the workflow initiator and your proposed solution sounds pretty reasonable. Along similar lines, you could start a secondary workflow for updating the metadata using the [Start Another Workflow](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20Another%20Workflow) activity which will run as the system user.

Another idea if you only need to capture the original submission is simply to copy it to a read-only library in the first step of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i am pretty sure that workflows always **do** run under system account?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is declarative workflow. Sorry, my mistake :(

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/09/28/declarative-workflows-and-user-context.aspx

Comment: You might want to do your own testing to validate.  In my experience, the system account or admin account is the account shown in the modified field when automated data updates are applied.

Comment: Nope every change is mad under initiator account (workflow starts when item is created). In article from MSDN above there is a number of people discussing the similar challenges but I wonder is the best practice.