# Workflow getting Access denied when calling the rest web service call

Tags: 2013, web-services, designer-workflow, rest

I have followed the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx) to give app permission to the Workflow and added the app step in the Workflow with elevated privilege. Under this step, made a web service call to

`{web url}/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='{AccountId}'`

However, got the same `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` message, as mentioned in the following [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70591/workflow-getting-access-denied-when-calling-the-rest-webservice-from-subsite/101274?noredirect=1#comment100600_101274).

Can somebody help identify where the issue is?

Comment: thanks Robert for the edit. I should have done it on my own :(

Comment: The following answer describes the problem quite well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800267/try-to-access-user-properties-using-user-profile-rest-api/43846273#43846273